# How To Have User Input Date and Subtract from It

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I want is a user input a selected date, and subtract that date from the current date, and then create a sleep timer according to the results.

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime
def ObtainDate():
    isValid=False
    while not isValid:
        userIn = raw_input("Type Date: mm/dd/yy: ")
        try:
            d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(userIn, "%m/%d/%y")
            isValid=True
        except:
            print "Invalid Format!\n"
    return d1

t = (datetime.now() - d1).seconds
```

My current current code looks like this, but I cannot figure out how to get d1 and subtract the current date from it.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://bpaste.net/show/PHTbTE99URHib7gsfUdd/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are importing the class using

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime
```

you are no longer importing the whole datetime module under that name, but individual classes directly into your script's namespace.  Therefore your input parsing statement should look like this:

```
d1 = datetime.strptime(userIn, "%m/%d/%y")  # You are no longer
```

The following will give you the difference in seconds between now and the entered time:

```
t = (datetime.now() - d1).total_seconds()
```

And as for the second part, there are many ways to implement a timer.  One simple way is

```
import time
time.sleep(t)
```

#### EDIT

Here is the whole thing together:

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

def ObtainDate():
    isValid=False
    while not isValid:
        userIn = raw_input("Type Date: mm/dd/yy: ")
        try:
            d1 = datetime.strptime(userIn, "%m/%d/%y")
            isValid=True
        except:
            print "Invalid Format!\n"
    return d1

t = (ObtainDate() - datetime.now()).total_seconds()
print t
```

Comment: Hmm... no longer lets me input a day, and I received this error

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: @Argutus Are you sure your import statement is `import datetime` and not `from datetime import datetime`?  If you're actually doing the latter, then you need `t = (datetime.now() - d1).seconds` instead.

Comment: Yes, I copied it down wrong, and I updated the OP. It now skips the user input, any ideas why?

Comment: @Argutus Yes - you've changed the way you import datetime, which changes the namespace, so you have to change how you refer to the imported classes.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Even with your solution user input is still broken. Sorry I don't mean to have you write the code entirely by yourself, I just get confused easily as I have been coding only for a day.

Comment: It's fine, although it's better not to keep editing the original code, because it creates a moving target for people helping you.  Also, it makes it much harder for future people looking at this thread to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few simple errors. This version works (though I'm not sure exactly what you need, it should get you past your immediate problem).

```
from datetime import datetime

def ObtainDate():
    while True:
        userIn = raw_input("Type Date: mm/dd/yy: ")
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(userIn, "%m/%d/%y")
        except ValueError:
            print "Invalid Format!\n"

t0 = datetime.now()
t1 = ObtainDate()
td = (t1 - t0)

print t0
print t1
print td
print td.total_seconds()
```

Your main problem was that you were not calling your function. I have also simplified your while loop to an infinite loop. The return statement will break out of the loop unless it raises an error.

Comment: Why is there `return d1` still at the end of the `ObtainDate` function?  It will never be reached, but if it were reached, it would result in a `NameError` being raised.