# Admission price based on age

Tags: python

I'm trying to come up with a program where you can calculate the admission price based on age. The prices are: 14 and under ($5.00), 15 to 64 ($9.00), and 65 and over ($7.50). The customer may also have a coupon that will take a dollar off of their price. So far I have come up with:

```
print ("Hello, welcome to Hopper's Computer Museum! To determine your enterance fee, please enter the following:")

print ('Your Date of Birth (mm dd yyyy)')
Date_of_Birth = input("--->")

print ('Todays Date: (mm dd yyyy)')
Todays_Date = input("--->")

age = (tYear-bYear)
if (bMonth > tMonth):
    age == age-1
if (bMonth == tMonth and
    bDay > tDay):
    age == age-1

price = -1
while price == -1:
    try:
        age = int(input('age:'))
    excpet ValueError:
        print("Not a number, try again.")
        continue
    if age <= 14:
        price==5.00
    elif age > 15 and age < 64:
        price==9.00
    else age > 65:
        price==7.50

print ('Do you have a coupon (y/n)?')
Discount = input("--->")
if Discount == "y" or Discount == "Y":
    price = price-1
elif Discount == "n" or Discount == "N":
    price = price

print ('Your admission fee is '+str(price)')
```

One thing that I am confused on would be how to get Python to take the dates that the user inputs and put it into the age calculation that I set up.

Comment: You might want to use `=` to assign values instead of `==` (checking for equality)...now that I think about it, double check all your `if` and `elif`statements.

Comment: @Jenna I hope you got your answer, if so Please [select the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify the format in which you want to take date and then split it like ...

```
import datetime
date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format')
year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))
date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

Or you can refer the following links for more info...

[getting-input-date-from-the-user-in-python-using-datetime-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581629/getting-input-date-from-the-user-in-python-using-datetime-datetime)

[how-to-have-user-input-date-and-subtract-from-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040057/how-to-have-user-input-date-and-subtract-from-it)

[how-do-i-take-input-in-the-date-time-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387596/how-do-i-take-input-in-the-date-time-format)

Comment: Where would I place this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a fixed format in which user will provide the date like `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`

**Then you can simply use:**

```
import datetime
date_time_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_provided, date_format)

#date_provided = '12/01/1995'
#date_format = '%d/%m/%Y'

curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()
time_diff = curr_time - date_time_object
print time_diff
age_days = time_diff.days
age_years = age_days / 326.25
print age_years
```